# Azure which Caching model to use In Memory (IMemoryCache) or Redis (IDistributedCache)

Tags: redis, azure-web-app-service, azure-caching

Hoping I could get some clarification on which Caching Mechanism is best for Azure.

Currently my App uses In Memory (IMemoryCache) to hold frequently accessed data.

Does this function as it would on a single Web Server? i.e stored in Memory once and accessed by each request?  or is this complicated by the Azure Web Server Farms?

Depending on the answer to the above, am I better to use Redis and the IDistributedCache model?

Answer (score 2):

The following the difference between  Memory cache and DistributedCache cache. You could choose it according to your requirement.

> The benefit of using **Memory cache** is it is **simple and fast**. However you **cannot scale your Web Apps** if you are using in memory provider since it is not distributed.
>
> Distributed In Memory Session State Provider such as **Redis Cache** Session State  Your Web App can have a **simple, fast, and scalable** Session State Provider. Because this provider stores the Session state in a Cache, your app has to take in consideration all the characteristics associated when talking to a Distributed In Memory Cache, such as transient network failures.
>
> For best practices on using Cache, see [Caching guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider) from Microsoft Patterns & Practices Azure Cloud Application Design and [Implementation Guidance](https://github.com/mspnp/elasticsearch).